# Recover a sent mail message

Tags: gmail

I penned a long email to 70 recipients of an organization.
I wasn't able to send it - I received an error message with prompts to use a different server.  After trying a few times I clicked the "try later" button.
But now I don't see the draft of my email anywhere in my Google Mail account.  How can I find it so I can try to resend?

Answer (score 1):

If it's not in "Drafts" and it's not in "Sent Mail", I'm afraid it's gone. Check "Trash", but I doubt it would be there.